# Where are aliases set in CentOS?

Tags: unix, centos, alias, bashrc

There is a typo which causes an error message upon logon (someone typed `lias` instead of `alias`). I have checked `/etc/bashrc` as well as `~/.bashrc` and `/etc/profile` as well as `~/.bash_profile` for individual users, but none of these files contain the custom aliases for the system. What alternate files can contain system-wide aliases?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Glad you found it, but here's a way to see all login files figure in the general sense:

```
# run strace, see every syscall
strace -o /tmp/bash.out bash --login
```

(Exit from bash shell)

```
# filter out opens that returned a descriptor, then use sed to get the file
< /tmp/bash.out grep -o 'open("[^,]*,[^)]*)[ \t]=[ \t][0-9]' | sed -e 's/^[^"]*"//' -e  's/".*$//' | sort -u > /tmp/openedfiles.txt

# grep for the broken alias, or whatever
< /tmp/openedfiles.txt xargs grep '^[ \t]*lias'
```

strace is one of those commands that can be magic if you know how to use it.

Comment: @ShouvikSayef this "run something under strace, see all the open files" works in a tremendous number of contexts. It's not a bad tool to have around. I have the filter (grep/sed) as a shell script to make it easier to invoke this pattern.

Answer (score 0):

found it:
/etc/profile.d/useralias.sh

Answer (score 0):

And for the quick and dirty crowd, I would have...

`grep ^lias ~/.* ; grep ^lias /etc/* /etc/*/*`

and if that didn't point me the right way, I'd have resorted to...

`grep alias ~/.* > /tmp/alias.txt ; grep alias /etc/* /etc/*/* >> /tmp/alias.txt ; less /tmp/alias.txt` and proofread all alias lines.